# How to clear the Text "1-1 of 0" in SimplePager (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Given these codes:

```
private ListDataProvider<String> cellListDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
public void onLoadingData(){
    mySimplePager.setDisplay(myCellList);
    mySimplePager.setPageSize(3);
    cellListDataProvider.addDataDisplay(myCellList);
}

//There is a button & when clicking that button , it will call
public void resetData(){
   cellListDataProvider.getList().clear();
   mySimplePager.setPageSize(0); ///--> dot no help
}
```

Now after calling `resetData()` then the `CellList` was disappeared, but the SimplePager still shows the text `1-1 of 0`, which doesn't make any sense. I tried to clear that text by using `mySimplePager.setPageSize(0);` but nothing happened unless I refresh the page.

So How to clear the Text "1-1 of 0" in SimplePager (GWT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is just to set the pager visibility to false when the count is 0, it will hide the whole pager.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mySimplePager.getDisplay().setRowCount(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

create your own pager.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.SimplePager;

public class NormalPager extends SimplePager{

      protected String createText() {
          if(getDisplay().getRowCount()==0){
                return "0 of 0";
            }else{
                return super.createText();
            }
          }   
}
```

because simple pager label come from **range.getStart() + 1;** and can't set minus value on range.

Comment: can u find a simpler solution, that is too much for a minor issue

Comment: I already read SimplePager.java and gave up to find another way.you can try to read SimplePager.java.

Comment: i put SimplePager in UiBinder, if i make a custom SimplePager then i need to go through some other process cos more codes. I need just siml 1 line of code to fix it.